# Strange content in the heap dump

Tags: android, heap-memory

I have gone through memory analysis process and I tried to read through and understand how to use the heap dumb in the monitor but I found some strange result. for example i found Bitmap but I have not used bitmap at this time. Can any one give me an overview of what is going on in my app memory.[image]

Comment: How can we know what is using bitmap without looking at the code? You may have some images in imageView.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I have some an image in the imageView from Drawable. Is this considered bitmap even if I do not define any bitmap.

Comment: how to delete the image in the imageView to release the memory.

Comment: use `imageView.setImageBitmap(null);` when no longer needed. Or the system will automatically clean it up after the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Many thanks, imageView.setImageBitmap(null); worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are using `Drawable` in `ImageView`, Drawables still use `Bitmap` internally. So you are seeing memory used up by the `Bitmap` object(s).